# Linux: make traffic from same host appear to come from different IP addresses

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I am using a client library (https://github.com/Beckhoff/ADS) to connect to a PLC from a Linux machine via TCP. However, the library is only able to perform a single connection between a source IP and the destination IP address of the PLC. My goal is to connect to the remote IP/PLC with multiple clients, i.e. the remote PLC must be able to distinguish the client connections based on the (different) IP address of the client.

I was hoping to accomplish this with some clever `iptables` rules; alternatively, maybe Linux network namespaces could work, too.

For the `iptables` route (pun?), my plan is to assign multiple IP addresses to the same NIC on the Linux machine. Since the remote service listens on a single port (48898) I cannot simply use different destination ports in the `iptables` rules. Therefore, I was thinking something like this:

Remote PLC: 192.168.1.10/24
Linux PC: 192.168.1.20/24 (ip addr add 192.168.1.20/24 dev enp2s0)
Linux PC: 192.168.1.21/24 (ip addr add 192.168.1.21/24 dev enp2s0)

- Client-A simply connects from 192.168.1.20 to 192.168.1.10
- Client-A simply connects from 192.168.1.21 to (virtual) 192.168.1.11

By using a "virtual" IP address for the remote PLC I want to be able to distinguish TCP connections, so I know what packets originate from Client-A and what packets originate from Client-B. Now I need to do some `iptables` magic along the lines:

1. **outgoing**: if destination IP address == 192.168.1.11
   1.1 -> rewrite to destination IP address 192.168.1.10
   1.1 -> rewrite/ensure source IP address is 192.168.1.21
2. **incoming**: if destination IP address == 192.168.1.21
   2.1 -> rewrite source IP address to 192.168.1.11 (virtual IP of remote PLC)

Maybe it is even possible to "tag" TCP connections so it would be easier to distinguish which is which (step 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case, *conntrack*'s NAT is enough to alter, tag and handle reply traffic correctly for the connection. One could use both DNAT and SNAT and bind their use together or use a mix of DNAT and adequate routes.

> [`DNAT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#DNAT)
>
> This target is only valid in the nat table, in the `PREROUTING` **and
> `OUTPUT`** chains, and user-defined chains which are only called from
> those chains. **It specifies that the destination address of the packet
> should be modified (and all future packets in this connection will
> also be mangled)**, and rules should cease being examined. [...]

> [`SNAT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#SNAT)
>
> This target is only valid in the nat table, **in the `POSTROUTING`** and
> `INPUT` chains, and user-defined chains which are only called from those
> chains. It specifies that **the source address of the packet should be
> modified (and all future packets in this connection will also be
> mangled)**, and rules should cease being examined. [...]

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.11 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.12 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.13 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.14 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10
```

set the additional source addresses on the client:

```
ip address add 192.168.1.21/24 dev enp2s0
ip address add 192.168.1.22/24 dev enp2s0
ip address add 192.168.1.23/24 dev enp2s0
ip address add 192.168.1.24/24 dev enp2s0
```

- and either bind the SNAT action conditionally to the *initial* destination address (before DNAT was done), using an adequate filter with *iptables*' [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#conntrack) match:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.1.11 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.21
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.1.12 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.22
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.1.13 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.23
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.1.14 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.24
  ```
- or instead of SNAT, much cleaner, use a route hinting directly the intended source address for each destination (even if nat/OUTPUT reroutes, the source address won't change anymore once set). This will allow the client and the `ss -tn dport == 48898` to know and display the correct source address. This becomes:

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.1.11/32 dev enp2s0 src 192.168.1.21
  ip route add 192.168.1.12/32 dev enp2s0 src 192.168.1.22
  ip route add 192.168.1.13/32 dev enp2s0 src 192.168.1.23
  ip route add 192.168.1.14/32 dev enp2s0 src 192.168.1.24
  ```

This has to be done like this: one address at a time (DNAT could be simplified/factorized, but not the second part dealing with source).

A connection to the actual `192.168.1.10` address is left unchanged.

Comment: many thanks @a-b - excellent solution and explanation - with this approach I managed to make everything work!!